# get addEventListener to go immediately

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code to replace svg generated image with a png
and I need it to fire immediately and not on 'load'. I have tried to set it on hover and it will go even without the original image being loaded - almost exactly as I want, except I want this to occur even without hover. How can I set an event that works immediately?

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('logo-header');

var src; // undefined

if (svg) {
    svg.addEventListener('load', function(event){    
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("logo-header", "im");
        img.src = src || "/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GSAlogo4.png";

        this.parentNode.replaceChild(img, this);
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: How about just removing the line where you wrap it into an event listener?

Comment: This code is part of a header and the whole header disappears if I remove it.. any way to set up a blank event? or event that is on immediately?

Comment: Do you need the event listener or you want to do that only once?

Answer (score 2):

If you were to do somehting like this.

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('logo-header');

var src; // undefined

if (svg) {
    (function(){    
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.setAttribute("logo-header", "im");
        img.src = src || "/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GSAlogo4.png";

        this.parentNode.replaceChild(img, this);
    })();
}
```

Make it an self-executing anonymous function.

But you could also just get it out of the function, that should work also

```js
var svg = document.getElementById('logo-header');

var src; // undefined

if (svg) {
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("logo-header", "im");
    img.src = src || "/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/GSAlogo4.png";

    this.parentNode.replaceChild(img, this);
}
```